# Using PHP scripts with android post requests

Tags: php, android, mysql, post

I'm using PHP scripts to handle the data I send from an android application as well as the data received from computers. My questions are as follow:

- If I use a php script using session variables how does that affect the request obtained from the android?
- Should I use separated php scripts while developing for android although they are meant to do the same?
- Is it safe to store and send "confidential" data like user id in the android device? (sharedPreferences).

Thank you for your help

Comment: SESSION is just based on an identifying cookie. Android requests can support cookies, so you can use sessions if you want. Any confidential data should be transmitted over https, regardless of wether its from a  desktop browser, or phone app

Comment: @user574632 does that mean I don't actually need shared preferences? If I have a log in which states that $_SESSION["X"] = Y then will the android device support that variable as well as all the others?

Comment: yes of course, you can put your session value by echo $_SESSION["x"] and android will see the value "Y" too. I think this question is about internet more then android question.